# Html nav element getting style on its own

Tags: jquery, razor

I have an element:

```
<nav id="datatableWithSearch" aria-label="Activity pagination"></nav>
```

on my cshtml view. When I inspect the element of this tag in the browser I noticed a style added to this nav. How is it possible.

Style added:

```
<nav id="datatableWithSearch" aria-label="Activity pagination" style="display:none">
```

As a temporary solution I have:

```
 <script>
    $(document).on('ready', function () {
        var element = document.getElementById("datatableWithSearch");
        element.style.display = null;
    });
 </script>
```

How do I improve on this because this only happens when document is loaded the first time.

Comment: What style is added? without knowing what style is added we can't give a good explanation to why

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen <nav id="datatableWithSearch" aria-label="Activity pagination" style="display:none">

Comment: Minor edit to make it slightly clearer

Comment: What libraries / script includes do you have?  Looks like something is picking up that it's `nav` to hiding all the the "active" one... maybe?  It's not doing it by itself (https://jsfiddle.net/26mncwpj/) so will be one of the other libraries.  Remove them all then add back one-by-one until it starts failing (or remove one-by-one until it stops failing).  Please see [mcve].  Without that info, it's just a guess, *maybe* someone had the same problem, but unlikely.